# DFA that accepts strings where there are odd number of 1's, and any number of 0's

Tags: automata, regular-language, regular-expressions, finite-automata

DFA that accepts strings where there are odd number of 1's, and any number of 0's.

The alphabet $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$

Well since it's odd $1$'s, then there must be at least **one** 1.

So I think the regex is the following:

$$R=0^*10^*$$

This is correct because I can have any number of $0's$, but also incorrect because I do not offer a way to add more 1's. How do I modify this $R$ so that I can have $3,5,7,\dots$ ones?

Comment: Holy 10K views damn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope it can help you

DFA that accepts strings having an odd number of $1$'s:
[image]
There are [several methods for reading a regular expression from a DFA](http://liacs.leidenuniv.nl/~bonsanguemm/FI2/DFA_to_RE.pdf). If we use the **state removal technique**:

this DFA are in Final form ,
regular expression for DFA is : $0^*1(0+1{0}^*1)^*$

---

> **Brzozowski Algebraic Method using [Arden's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arden%27s_Rule)**
>
> Note that when we apply Arden's theorem, the transition graph does not
>   have $\epsilon-moves$ and it should have only one initial state, say
>   $N_1$.
>
> 1. its vertices are $N_1,N_2,....N_n.$
> 2. $N_i$ is the regular expression representing the set of strings accepted by the system even though $V_i$ is finial state.
> 3. $\alpha_{ij}$ denotes the regular expression representing the set of labels of edges from $N_i$ to $N_j$,when there is no such edge,
>      $\alpha_{ij}=\emptyset$
>
> consequently, we can get the set of equations.here $\epsilon$ should
>   be added in the equation of initial state $N_1$, i.e.
>
> \begin{align} &N_1=N_1\alpha_{11}+N_2\alpha_{21}+ ...
>  +N_n\alpha_{n1}+\epsilon \\ &N_2=N_1\alpha_{12}+N_2\alpha_{22}+ ... +N_n\alpha_{n2} \\ .\\ .\\ .\\ &N_n=N_1\alpha_{1n}+N_2\alpha_{2n}+ ... +N_n\alpha_{nn} \\ \end{align}
>
> by repeatedly applying substitution and Arden's theorem, we get $N_i$
>   in terms of $\alpha_{ij}$'s.if there are more final states,then we have
>   to take the union of all $N_i$'s corresponding to the final states.
>
> ---
>
> "Introduction to Automata and Compiler Design - Dasaradh Ramaiah K."

If we use the Brzozowski Algebraic Method:
\begin{align}
&q_0=q_00+q_11+\epsilon \\
&q_1=q_01+q_10
\end{align}

by Arden's theorem ($r=rp+q$ has only solution $r=qp^*$) for $q_1$ we have:
\begin{align}
&q_1=q_010^* \tag{1}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
&q_0=q_00+q_010^*1+\epsilon \\
&\,\,\,\,\,=q_0(0+10^*1)+\epsilon
\end{align}
by Arden's theorem for $q_0$ we have:

\begin{align}
&q_0=(0+10^*1)^* \tag{2}
\end{align}

final regular expression is: $$(0+1{0}^*1)^*10^* \tag{1,2}$$

Answer (score 0):

So after the first 1, you want any other 1s to come in pairs. $0^*10^*10^*$ gives you a pair of 1s, $(0^*10^*10^*)^*$ gives you any number of pairs of 1s, so $$0^*10^*(0^*10^*10^*)^*$$ should do the trick.